# How to "share" a screen session?

Tags: bash, display

Is it possible to start a screen session and have some other process attach to it without having the original process detaching it? Like two terminal windows seeing the same, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible and extremely useful.

In order to attach an already attached screen session, to enter multi-user mode, the option you have to give `screen` is simply `screen -x`.